# Move item after downloaded

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, download, document

I am working on a file download currently. After the download is finished I want to move the downloaded file to the apps document directory, my setup:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    debugPrint("didFinishDownloadingTo: \(location)")

    let documentsDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let saveDirectory = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("file1.mp4")

    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: saveDirectory)
    } catch {
        print("didFinishDownloadingTo error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

At some point I want to see all my downloaded files:

```
do {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = String(describing: paths[0])

    let items = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectory)

    for item in items {
        print("Found \(item)")
    }
} catch {
    print("contentsOfDirectory \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

This part throws:

```
The folder “Documents” doesn’t exist.
```

The *didFinishDownloadingTo* method throws no error, so I assume the moveitem function succeeded, but I have no idea why I cant list my items...
I did some research, but with no result and I dont know why I can't list.

Comment: Don't use `String(describing:)` method. It will return your url `absoluteString` which includes the "file://" prefix (url scheme). Just use your document directory url path property. `FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: paths.first!.path)`

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging by simply printing the paths and check those folders. This way you can see which step is not working as expected. I think there is a small mistake with paths which might be easier to catch while debugging.

Tip: debug using simulator but not a real device. Since it will make it much easier just to navigate through the folders.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OP problem is using the url absoluteString which includes the url scheme.

Comment: what is OP? @LeoDabus

Comment: original poster (Creative crypter) :)

Comment: gotcha. thanks:) @LeoDabus

Comment: @LeoDabus may I ask why do you prefer answering in comments rather than in answers section so that people see the solution?

Comment: I am not supposed to answer it twice :(

Comment: sure, but then you could give a link to original answer:) @LeoDabus

Comment: See the duplicate at the top

Comment: gotcha. sorry:) thanks @LeoDabus